# Can I store the results of the summary function in R?

Tags: r, summary

I have lists in R (given by collaborators). Each list has a boolean variable called "er", and I would like to compute the ratio of TRUE/FALSE. However, there might be NA.

I applied the summary function on one list and got

```
Mode        FALSE    TRUE   NA's
"logical"   "199"    "798"  "0"
```

I tried to store the results with:

```
table <- summary(....)
```

R accepts the command, but I don't see anything in my environment. Any hint would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: this works fine for me, the variable is saved to the global env with the table inside

Comment: @BrodieG Hi! Thank you for your input! Could it be because I am on a server?

Comment: What happens with`print(table)`

Answer (score 2):

It appears to work just fine:

```
ER <- c(TRUE, FALSE, NA, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE)
a <- summary(ER)
print(a)
#   Mode   FALSE    TRUE    NA's 
#logical       4       3       1
```

But if you're interested in a table, take a look of the function of the same name:

```
b <- table(ER, useNA = "ifany")
print(b)
#ER
#FALSE  TRUE  <NA> 
#    4     3     1
```

This should also illustrate why you might want to avoid making a variable called `table`.

**Edit** If you want the proportion of `TRUE` and `FALSE` entries then something like

```
b/sum(b)
#ER
#FALSE  TRUE  <NA> 
#0.500 0.375 0.125
```

or

```
b/sum(!is.na(ER))
#ER
#    FALSE      TRUE      <NA> 
#0.5714286 0.4285714 0.1428571
```

should work depending on whether you want to count the `NA`s. In the latter, the number given under the `NA`s is meaningless.

**Edit2** Or even better, take a look at `prop.table` as suggested by Gregor in the comments.

Comment: Thank you for your input. However, I would like to access the number of TRUE's and FALSE's to compute fraction. I tried b$TRUE, and I get an error.

Comment: You can compute fraction by `sum(ER,na.rm=T)/sum(!ER,na.rm=T)` (the trick is that `sum` will coerce logical T/F into numeric 1/0)

Comment: @Johnathan `str(summary(ER))`

Comment: For proportions, I'd use `prop.table(table(ER))`.

Answer (score -1):

<strike>You cannot see anything in your environment because with</strike>

Apparently it appears in the var list, though you should be careful because with

```
table <- summary(...)
```

you are overwriting the built-in function `table()`, which btw is the one you should be using instead of `summary`.
For instance

```
l <- rep(c(T,F,NA),c(798,199,0))
freq <- table(l,useNA="always")
```

Comment: Thanks! So, let's say that I simply want R to count the instances of TRUE and FALSE and store them in a data.frame, could you please give me a hint?

Comment: It depends on how you want your data frame formatted, the simplest way is to add  `df <- as.data.frame(t)`.

Comment: @Johnathan if you thanked me why then you down voted me?

Comment: I downvoted you because your answer is wrong.  Try `sum <- 1; sum; ls(pattern="sum")` to see what I mean.

Comment: @MTk That's weird because I have not voted you down. Here, I have voted you up. :)

Comment: @MTk I have used the subset function, and it works! :)

Comment: By assigning the table to `t` you're overwriting the built-in transpose function `t()`. Overwriting base functions shouldn't be done willy-nilly, but it's not the worst thing either.